# Can't install laravel-elixir because of node-sass failure

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-elixir, node-sass

I am pretty new to this environment still and am trying to get up to speed on node.js modules and Laravel (5.1.11) as a whole, so...

I have a fresh install of Laravel implemented by the cPanel Installitron. I'm using PHPStorm to install all of the node modules via the provided `package.json`:

**package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-elixir": "^3.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

The error I get when I run the install is:

```
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-57_binding.node": 

HTTP error 404 Not Found
```

I can understand why this would happen, seeing as that is an older version of `node-sass`, but how do I know what newer versions are compatible with the requested version of `laravel-elixir`? I didn't want to just install a newer version of `node-sass` because digging a deeper hole would make it harder for me to find a solution to my problem. What is the fix for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you can fix this by installing Windows Build Tools via this command:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Then delete the project's `node_modules` folder and re-run `npm install`.

Comment: OMG ExcellentSP. Why didn't I see this answer 2 months ago!? This worked on Windows 10 running Laravel 5.2. We had to update one package to using Mix because we were getting a bunch of Python errors. You have saved me BIG time! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this `official` url well doc.: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir if you get any error. I just comment and i ll be here.

Comment: If you have till error, its might `version dependency` with your `laravel version`.